# Simple DropDownList in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Working on my first MVC3 app.  I have a simple View that has 2 objects (object A, object B).  Object B is optional.  I've created a Model with both objects and have the Controller working just fine passing the data back and forth to the View.

I'm trying to put in a simple DropDownList for the user to decide whether they want to enter data for object B.  The dropdown list is simple - two values "Yes" and "No". 
Ex:  Continue with Part "B"?
[Yes]
[No]

On the View, the user fills out all of the form items of object A.  Then, they have a choice to fill out the items of object B.  I want them to select "Yes" if they want to do that (I'm using Jquery to show more of the page at that time).

My question:  How do I make a simple Dropdownlist (or even a basic HTML input type="select"...) that I can access in the Controller after they submit the form?

In my Controller, I want to do the following:
* Do stuff for object A
* Check to see if they selected Yes
* Do stuff for object B

Does something as simple as a Yes/No dropdown need to go into the Model? Its not typed to anything - its just a decision made by the user in the View.  I know there has to be a simple way of doing this (ViewBag?) but I'm new and apparently lost.

TL;DR - How do I create as simple DropdownList on a View that I can access in the Controller?

Comment: Ok - I can use Request.Form["ddlChoice"]; in the controller and that will work.  Is that the best way to do it?

Comment: please see my answer below, I feel like there is more code bloat and is more prone to error if you use the Request.Form attributes instead of using a strongly typed class. If you feel the below answer helps please mark as an answer, have a good one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule of thumb for getting values from the view back in the HTTPPOST for your object is to name the input controls id and name properties the same as the Models property name. An easy way to do this is to use Html helpers.

```
    public class Model
    {
        public Model()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> options = new List<SelectListItem>();
            options.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = true.ToString(), Text = "yes" });
            options.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = false.ToString(), Text = "no" });
            ContinueOptions = options;
        }
        public bool Continue { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ContinueOptions { get; set; }
    }
```

In your View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Continue, Model.ContinueOptions)
```

In your Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Model model)
{
    bool continueOn = model.Continue;   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes your drop down should be part of the model, otherwise the controller won't have the answer from the user to *Check to see if they selected Yes*.

```
public SomeViewModel
{
  public ObjectA A { get; set; }
  public ObjectB B { get; set; }
  public bool? IsBSelected { get; set; }
}
```

I usually use `bool?` simply because I like to know if the user selected on or the other, but using `bool` would be fine too.